# Padding with spaces and number formatting XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, padding, number-formatting

Im trying to reformat weight values to not have any decimal places and always have six characters. Ive managed to work out how to pad with zeros but i cant seem to make it work with spaces. Any ideas?

Input:

```
<Weight>1150.0</Weight>
```

xlst:

```
<Weight><xsl:value-of select="format-number(Weight,'######')"/></Weight>
```

Expected output:

```
<Weight>  1150</Weight>
```

Current Output:

```
<Weight>001150</Weight>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
<xsl:variable name="int" select="round(Weight)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('      ', $int), 1 + string-length($int))"/>
```

If your processor supports it, you could use the [EXSLT `str:align()` extension function](https://web.archive.org/web/20211025221817/http://exslt.org/str/functions/align/index.html):

```
<xsl:value-of select="str:align(round(Weight), '      ', 'right')"/>
```

---

Note that the two methods will behave differently when the integer has more than 6 digits.

Comment: hi michael - how could i avoid NaN values using this method? this is currently only adding one space to the result

Comment: Which value of `Weight` gives you a result of `Nan`?

Comment: When no value for weight is supplied, this should become 0

Comment: Then use `xsl:choose` to branch between the two.

Comment: Or just do `<xsl:variable name="int" select="round(concat('0', Weight))"/>`.